# Specify point singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory, singularity

I have problem with point singularities at $\infty$. For example: Determine the nature of the point at infinity functions. For zero or pole enter times.
we have function $f(z)=\frac{z-\frac{\pi}{2}}{cosz}$. So in this function we have regular point at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ times one. And I don't know how to determine this point at infity function. Can someone explain me?

Comment: Why $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ is pole.?

Comment: My bad it's regular point

Comment: What's the definition of a pole?

Comment: @MyGlasses $z_0$ is a pole when $\lim\limits_{z->z_0}f(z)=\infty$

Comment: Well, what about your function.?

Comment: @MyGlasses in point $\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have regular point but in $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ without $0$  we have pole times one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52310/discussion-between-myglasses-and-zxc).